# How to tell apache to rewrite to another directory if file not found?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to know how to modify my .htaccess file to tell Apache to look inside another directory if a particular file is not found. In the example below the directory /dir could have thousands of missing files ranging in file type that may exist in /dir2.

For instance I have:

```
domain.com/dir/
```

If file not found, try

```
domain.com/dir2/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the **-f** in the [RewriteCond patterns](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to test if a file exists. So you'd be working with something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^dir/(.+)$ /dir2/$1 [L]
```

If the file isn't in dir2, then you'd get the regular 404 message.